# Greedy algorithm for largest value in dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I've been working on the greedy algorithm in this [problem set from OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/assignments/pset8.pdf).

So far I have this:

```
def greedyAdvisor(subjects, maxWork, comparator):
    """
    Returns a dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work) which includes
    subjects selected by the algorithm, such that the total work of subjects in
    the dictionary is not greater than maxWork.  The subjects are chosen using
    a greedy algorithm.  The subjects dictionary should not be mutated.

    subjects: dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work)
    maxWork: int >= 0
    comparator: function taking two tuples and returning a bool
    returns: dictionary mapping subject name to (value, work)
    """
    greedySchedule = {}
    currentWork = 0 
    nameList = []
    workValueList = []
    for name, workValue in subjects.items():
        nameList.append(name)
        workValueList.append(workValue)
    while currentWork <= maxWork:
        for i in range(len(workValueList) - 2): 
            for j in range(i, len(workValueList) - 1): 
                if comparator(workValueList[i], workValueList[j]):
                    bestKey = nameList[i]
                    bestTuple = workValueList[i]
                    currentWork += workValueList[i][WORK]
                    jWasPicked = False
                else:
                    bestKey = nameList[j]
                    bestTuple = workValueList[j]
                    currentWork += workValueList[j][WORK]
                    jWasPicked = True
                if currentWork > maxWork:
                    break
                if jWasPicked:
                    break
            if currentWork > maxWork:
                break
            greedySchedule[bestKey] = bestTuple
    return greedySchedule
```

The comparators are:

```
VALUE = 0
WORK = 1

def cmpValue(subInfo1, subInfo2):
    """
    Returns True if value in (value, work) tuple subInfo1 is GREATER than
    value in (value, work) tuple in subInfo2
    """
    val1 = subInfo1[VALUE]
    val2 = subInfo2[VALUE]
    return  val1 > val2

def cmpWork(subInfo1, subInfo2):
    """
    Returns True if work in (value, work) tuple subInfo1 is LESS than than work
    in (value, work) tuple in subInfo2
    """
    work1 = subInfo1[WORK]
    work2 = subInfo2[WORK]
    return  work1 < work2

def cmpRatio(subInfo1, subInfo2):
    """
    Returns True if value/work in (value, work) tuple subInfo1 is 
    GREATER than value/work in (value, work) tuple in subInfo2
    """
    val1 = subInfo1[VALUE]
    val2 = subInfo2[VALUE]
    work1 = subInfo1[WORK]
    work2 = subInfo2[WORK]
    return float(val1) / work1 > float(val2) / work2
```

Whenever I run this it only gives me the subjects in the order they come in on the list. The dictionary I'm using is:

```
small_catalog = {'6.00': (16, 8), '1.00': (7, 7), '6.01': (5, 3), '15.01': (9, 6)}
```

It always returns `{'1.00': (7,7), '15.01': (9, 6)}` when `maxWork` is `15`
I'm using a specific `printSubjects` function that returns subjects in order based on the numerical order of the names. For instance when I use it for the `small_catalog`, it prints

```
{'1.00': (7, 7), '15.01': (9, 6), '6.00': (16, 8), '6.01': (5,3)}
```

Obviously this is a little flawed because `15.01` should be last but that isn't the point. The point is that it always prints in the order of this dictionary while limiting the workload to `maxWork` which is `15`.

Comment: Where do you define `VALUE` and `WORK`? I did this problem set a while back. Would you like me to post a more concise solution or are you strictly looking for debugging help? For example, you will have a much easier time if you sort your subjects.

Comment: Get subject names `nameList` convert all elements to `float()` and sort it - then convert all elements to `str()` and you get `['1.00', '6.00', '6.01', '15.01']` - then use that list to get elements directly from  `subjects` in place of `workValueList[x]`

Comment: I'm looking for a debugging help because I want to be able to have an original solution. I believe WORK = 1 and Value = 0.

Comment: OK I searched for a solution online, and they used selection sort to sort the keys in the dictionary based on the comparators. Then they placed the largest values of the sorted list in the new dictionary until maxWork was reached. Is it bad that I used someone else's solution? I understood the code, but did I not learn anything?

Comment: Did they use function `sorted()` ?

Comment: No they added all the keys to a new list and used selection sort to sort the list. This is because sorted sorts lists differently from the comparators so you want to manually create a sorting algorithm with the comparators.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework assignment, we shouldn't just give away the answer.  So here are some hints:

- Look at the sorted() to rank order "best" candidates in order.
- Use a "key function" or "cmp function" to pass in the metric of merit.
- Loop through the result list accumulating results until you hit "max".

Here's a resource to get your started:

- https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html